# How to check whether my server has assigned any cron job or not

Tags: php, cron, cpanel, cron-task

Is it possible to check the list of cron jobs that has assigned to my server using putty or winscp or some other ways to check .Because I could find cron job tab in side my cpanel

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can check for current user

```
crontab -l
```

For list of commands available [crontab usage](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/ucrontab.htm)

For all user take a look at:

```
/var/cron/tabs
#OR
/var/spool/cron/crontabs
```